# Is that easy to turn a centralized app into a dApp hosted on Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, javascript

Currently I have an app that I use on my own servers. It is coded with JavaScript and PHP. The code is ready, I mean already exists.

Would it be difficult to turn it into a dApp using smart-contracts, hosted on Ethereum blockchain ?

Comment: could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 5):

> Short Answer - It's a non-trivial effort.

Reasons -

- Architecture would not be the same
- Storage can be a problem (You may have to use IPFS or Swarm for storage issues)
- Upgradable smart contract (You need to make sure that the smart contract you are writing is upgradable because contract once deployed on blockchain shall not be killed, if killed then you will loose all your data)
- You need to decide whether the app use case is fit for Private or
  Public blockchain. Both need a bit of brainstorming before you proceed